# Scrapy xpath-selector doesn't work with this html tag

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors, web-crawler

I have a case where inside the body of a website there is another html tag which i can not access using an Xpath or a CSS selector using scrapy. The html tag is as follows:

[HTML tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLWpv.png)

Also, here is the website:https://www.hmm21.com/cms/business/ebiz/schedule/trade/index.jsp

When i am trying to use a selector for an item inside this html tag it seems like scrapy can't find it. Do you have any idea what is goin on?

Comment: Hi ! Next time, please copy/paste the part of the code that you want the community to watch, instead of a screenshot, it's easier to read, and to comment on.

Answer (score 0):

That's because [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) require an additional request. Although browsers do that transparently, you have to do that yourself when writing your own crawler. Eg:

```py
class HMMSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hmm"
    start_urls = ["https://www.hmm21.com/cms/business/ebiz/schedule/trade/index.jsp"]

    def parse(self, response):
        iframe_url = response.css("#_frame1::attr(src)").get()
        yield response.follow(iframe_url, callback=self.parse_iframe)

    def parse_iframe(self, response):
        for tab in response.css(".new_ul_tab a::text").getall():
            self.logger.debug(f"I'm in the {tab} tab")
```